# Display latest 31 records and last working business day(excluding Saturday, Sunday but can include holidays) of every month in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I want to display each 31 latest records for each of these values - Blue, Red, green and last business day for every month for these 3 values and all violet records.

```
Color   Count   date
blue    3   2019-03-24
red     4   2019-03-24
green   2   2019-03-24
violet  1   2019-03-23
blue    3   2019-03-23
... ... ...
Blue    31  2016-01-31
```

Business day means last day of the month, if it's saturday or sunday then friday should be shown. If it's a weekday then that day will be last business day of month.

I created the below query but it does not show me every month's last business day. What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to do this query?

```
SELECT  color,count,date
FROM(
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY color ORDER BY date DESC) RN
     FROM table
    ) V
WHERE V.RN < 32
     AND color  IN ('blue','Red','Green') or color = 'violet'
     and CAST(DATEADD(d, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, date) + 1, 0)) - CASE DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, date) + 1, 0)))
        WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN 2
        WHEN 'SATURDAY' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS DATE) != CAST(date AS DATE) 
    and color  IN ('blue','Red','Green') or color = 'violet'    
    order by color desc
```

**Expected Output: first 31 records of blue, first 31 records of red, first 31 records of green and their last business day (excluding weekends only) for every month and all records of violet.**

What I am getting is 31 records for each 3 values and all violet records but not last business day for each month

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: What if the last Friday of the month is a holiday?

Comment: If last Friday of month is holiday, it should still be displayed. Only weekends should be excluded.

Comment: One thing I can see is the placement of 'OR violet' in your script . try this (color  IN ('blue','Red','Green')    and CAST(DATEADD(d, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, date) + 1, 0)) - CASE DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, date) + 1, 0)))
        WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN 2        WHEN 'SATURDAY' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS DATE) != CAST(date AS DATE) )  OR  color = 'violet'

Comment: Aside: If you are using a reasonably current version of SQL Server you may want to look at the [`EOMonth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Comment: I've tried that too.. but I think my logic of fetching 31 rows and last business days gets a conflict.. I'm getting either last business day only or latest 31 records.. can't figure out what logic should I use

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. There's only small changes at two places and now the query works just fine.

The correct query is:

```
SELECT  color,count,date
FROM(
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY color ORDER BY date DESC) RN
     FROM table
    ) V
WHERE RN < 32
     AND color  IN ('blue','Red','Green') OR color = 'violet'
     OR CAST(DATEADD(d, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, date) + 1, 0)) 
     - CASE DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, date) + 1, 0)))
        WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN 2
        WHEN 'SATURDAY' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS DATE) = CAST(date AS DATE)
    and color  IN ('blue','Red','Green') OR color = 'violet'    
    ORDER BY color desc
```